# How to track React hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Before working on a new React project, I want to be sure that there are (or will be), good developer tools to support it.

One of the things I like with React is the React Developer tool for Google Chrome. It lets me inspect the internal state for each component.

**The question:** Does the React Developer tool show the hooks state of a React component?

If not, how can I inspect the internal hooks state (Aka effect), outside of the React component?

Comment: [not yet](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/1215)

Comment: the [devtools](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/1215) support for hooks is [WIP and is not available yet.](https://twitter.com/sophiebits/status/1063004723085635584).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Today, the [Chrome Developers React toolbar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) is able to show the state of hooks.

See the attached image:

[image]

Comment: How would you then figure out the name of that State? Doesn't really make sense just to use State and the value.

Comment: @Tanckom In practice, I haven't found this to be a big issue. I rarely have so many similar values that it's confusing and they appear in dev tools in the same order that they were created in the component so I can always check my code if I need to double check.

Answer (score 15):

Short answer is no, React Devtool doesn't exactly show the hooks state of components **the way you want it to**. You could track the progress of its implementation [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/1215).

The long answer is yes, the React Devtool technically does show state for hooks, but not in a user-friendly format that you are used to. The state is being shown in its raw implementation form, which resembles a linked list:

```
{
  baseState: ...,
  baseUpdate: ...,
  memoizedState: ...,
  next: {
    baseState: ...,
    baseUpdate: ...,
    memoizedState: ...,
    next: ..., // The list goes on
    queue: ...,
  },
  queue: ...
}
```

For a simple component with two states, the Devtool shows state as an object with `baseState` field as the first state value of `'Mary'` and there's a `next` field which points to another state object which corresponds to the second state value, and it has the `baseState` value of `10`.

```
function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('Mary');
  const [age, setAge] = useState(10);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Name: {name}</p>
      <p>Age: {age}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can inspect React.useState with [react-debug-hooks](https://github.com/aldosota/react-debug-hooks) and [Redux DevTools](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools)

[inspect preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ox1jS.png)

```
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    loading: false,
    users: [],
    error: null
  }, 'users')  // you need to set a second parameter 'string' that will be shown on Redux devTools.
```